# Inserting data from R to SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server

I am trying to insert data from R into SQL Server, using JDBC with Append Table.

```
dbAppendTable`(conn = conn,
          name = " test",
          value = data,
          append = TRUE)
```

But I am getting this warning and error message:

> Warning message in if (is.na(v)) {:
> “the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used”
>
> Error in .verify . JDBC .result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ", : Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for INSERT INTO `" d b o .test "`
> (The value is not set for the parameter number 2.).

How can I resolve this or some other solution for inserting data with RJDBC?

Comment: This is hard to debug, but from your error it is trying to insert values into a schema, table pair named " d b o .test ". Note the whitespace. So start by removing whitespace from `name = " test"`. Next you should look at your statement for `conn` and make sure that you have stated your table schema correctly. A schema can "technically" have spaces (but please do smack your DB admin if it does), but it is more likely that you are trying to insert into  `dbo.test` and have inserted unnecessary whitespaces. For `is.na(v)` this is within the function call.

Comment: And it indicates that either there's a bug in the implementation or maybe you are providing unexpected input to `dbAppendTable`. I would fix the remaining bugs first and see if this "magically" disappears.

Comment: Thank you on answer...this spaces are written by mistake, it is dbo.test and I checked all columns in data frame and data table are the same, there is no missing and NA values...

Comment: My next guess is that there are additional colums in `dbo.test` that are not present in your `data.frame`. You could also try using odbc to connect to the database.